# std::queue::empty() not working?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue, mutex

I'm going crazy with this piece of code. I have a thread that calls regularly to this method:

```
void deliverMsgQ() {        
    if(delMsgQ_mutex.try_lock() == false){
        return;
    }            
    while(delMsgQ.empty() == false){                
        std::vector<unsigned char> v = delMsgQ.front(); 
        delMsgQ.pop();                  
    }
    delMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
}

void processInMsgQ() {
    if(inMsgQ_mutex.try_lock()){
       if(delMsgQ_mutex.try_lock() == false){
           inMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
       } 
    }else{
        return;
    }

    while(!inMsgQ.empty()){            
        std::vector<unsigned char> msg;
        inMsgQ.front()->getData(msg); 
        std::cout << "Adding to del-msg-q: " << msg.size() << std::endl;
        delMsgQ.push(msg);
        delete inMsgQ.front();
        inMsgQ.pop();            
    }
    inMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
    delMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
}
```

I have another thread pushing vector to the queue also periodically. These two threads are the only ones that touch the queue `delMsgQ`.

My problems comes in the first function posted, for some reason `delMsgQ.empty()` at some point returns false even though it has no vectors in it, and therefore I end up calling pop twice. This causes the size function to become a huge unrealistic number and then the program goes into segmentation fault. I can fix this if I add an additional check right before calling pop, but I would expect that checking once would be enough since I'm also using mutexes. So the other alternative would be that maybe I'm using mutexes wrong, but as far as I know this is the proper way to use them in this case. So I was hoping that maybe someone smarter could let me know if there is something I'm missing? I hope this code is enough, I can provide with more code if necessary although no other function touch the queue that is failing.

best regards

Comment: You probably have a race condition. You'll have to make access to the queue (reading and writing) using a synchronization mechanism, e.g. a `std::mutex`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You mean a mutex for writing and a mutex for reading? ha, didnt think about that, Ill try it.

Comment: In the `processInMsgQ` if you fail to lock `delMsgQ_mutex` then you still continue with the function with both mutexes unlocked.

Comment: No I meant one for both cases. Also you should use it with the `std::lock_guard`, instead of locking unlocking manually.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:Ha!, perfect, this did it. Thanks a lot, ill go and get a new pair of eyes now.

Comment: Not sure if it is the underlying cause, but did you intent to continue with the processInMsgQ method when try_lock failed for delMsgQ_Mutex?

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `processInMsgQ()` (spaced out a little better but functionally identical) is problematic:

```cpp
if (inMsgQ_mutex.try_lock()) {
    if (delMsgQ_mutex.try_lock() == false) {
        // Point A
        inMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
        // Point B.
    }
} else {
    return;
}
// Point C.
```

In the case where it locks `inMsgQ_mutex` but fails to lock `delMsgQ_mutex` (point A), it will free the first and then drop through to point C. This means you will be doing stuff that requires both locks without *either* lock, and that's unlikely to end well :-)

As a solution, you *could* put another `return` at point B but the following code is probably cleaner:

```cpp
// If either lock fails, return ensuring that neither is locked.

if (! inMsgQ_mutex.try_lock()) {
    return;
}
if (! delMsgQ_mutex.try_lock() {
    inMsgQ_mutex.unlock();
    return;
}

// At this point, you have both locks. Carry on ...
```

You'll notice I've also changed your `some_boolean == false` to the more usual `! some_boolean`. That's the more accepted way of doing that particular check.